# AngularJS - define an object but don't run ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem where I need to build a content type.  First, I define my model.  I'm using Drupal so I need to send values nested in things like:

```
field_whatever.und[0].value = "";
```

Say I define an array for images:

```
$scope.field_my_images = {"und": [{}]};
```

Because I have a blank array:

```
<div ngRepeat="image in field_my_images.und"><img ng-src="{{image.url}}" /></div>
```

Will print the first array element blank. As I push new objects to field_my_images, it works correctly except for the first blank element.

What's the proper way to do this?

I can add details and be more specific as needed....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

shouldn't you initialize your scope with this instead?

```
$scope.field_my_images = {"und": []};
```

Otherwise, you don't have an empty array, you have an array with an empty object.

Comment: Oh, wow... yeah.  I started with a select list and for that I had to define the object within the array, but for everything else I didn't.  Thank You!